# Run a php script from within wordpress plugin directory using only a page anchor link

Tags: php, wordpress

Run a php script from within wordpress plugin directory using only a page anchor link.

I have created a plugin that searches for duplicate posts in the DB. It works fine. However, I need to display the list of duplicates and have a link that allows the user to delete that post.

Right now I have the php script in the web root and call it like a standard php script. However, I would like to move that script into the plugin directory and have the link point to the php script in the plugin directory.

Is there a way to tell wordpress that it can execute a stand alone script in the plugin directory. My efforts so far have been "page not found".

The url is formatted like this:
"domain.com/script-name?delete=post_id"

What I am looking for is something like this: 
"domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/script-name?delete=post_id.

Wordpress doesn't seem to like you requesting a script direct from the plugin directory.

Comment: Why would you not just actually create a Wordpress plugin that you can use to accomplish this? Then it would reside in your plugins directory naturally and fit better within the framework.

Comment: Robert, Not sure what you are saying perhaps you are more experienced than most wordpress users.

Comment: Actually I don't care much for Wordpress, but I have had to work in it enough to know that it's not a complicated process to write a simple plugin.  There are a lot of tutorials out there that explain the process... this one for instance: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-plugin-development-guide/?utm_expid=3606929-84.YoGL0StOSa-tkbGo-lVlvw.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Comment: you can edit the htaccess file to allow your file to be visited or you can use custom rewrites which would be preferable.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - but I was looking for an integrated solution to the plugin directory. I will just leave the standalone script in the root directory and call it from there.